# What does the phrase "Rokkon Shojo" mean?

Tags: japanese-language, koutetsujou-no-kabaneri

In one of the most popular anime of this season, **Koutetsujou no Kabaneri**,  before, in the middle or after a battle, the human combatants yell **"Rokkon Shojo"** or  the Princess says it after a battle.
I researched a bit and apparently it means “**purification of the six roots of perception”** (which is quite ambiguous) .

My questions are:

1. It has any other meaning other than the one stated above?
2. What is its purpose and why is it used in a  situation which involves fighting?

Comment: Rock on, Shoujo!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rokkon shojo does indeed mean purification of the six roots of perception. By my current knowledge there is no other meaning to it.

The usage however that is most known to people is during mountain climbing, or as [haikugirl.me](https://haikugirl.me/2014/12/14/word-of-the-week-rokkonshojo/) phrases it

> ‘rokkon shojo’ is a common expression often repeated while climbing a mountain, especially Mount Fuji. ‘Rokkon’ (六根) means ‘six senses’ (i.e. seeing, hearing, smelling, tasting, touching and conciousness). ‘Shojo’ (清浄) means ‘purification’. So, the phrase refers to purifying your heart of all the bad stuff (desire, anger, fear, depression, etc.) that comes from what we take in via the six senses.

However this would not make a lot of sense in [koutetsujou-no-kabaneri](/questions/tagged/koutetsujou-no-kabaneri). The way [ja.wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%AD%E6%A0%B9%E6%B8%85%E6%B5%84) describes it.

> そのため執着を断ち、心を清らかな状態にすることを言う。そのため不浄なものを見ない、聞かない、嗅がない、味わわない、触れない、感じないために俗世との接触を絶つことが行なわれた（山ごもりなど）。

This is a phrase as referred to in Buddhism. Which would roughly translate to something like

> Cut of your obsessions, refer to your heart in a pure state. Do not see what is unclean, do not ask, smell, taste or touch. Cut off your contact with the world **in order not to feel**.

This does fit the series a bit better. By killing of your emotions, it will make it easier to kill. This is something used in the modern day military as wel.

It also fits into the series given that

> a monster cannot be defeated unless its heart, which is protected by a layer of iron, is pierced.

making `refer to your heart in a pure state` which I believe can also be interpreted as `cutting of ones heart` (please correct me if I am wrong) a fair pun of sorts.

Answer (score 3):

a Chinese here. We have the same phrase in Chinese, however, I am not entirely sure if it means the exact same thing.
六根, refers to the five senses and your consciousness (soul).
清净 refers to a state of being clean and not polluted. 
It is a Buddhism concept referring to to a state of personal purity. It means that you are no longer bound by worldly desires and are free of it. It is usually used to describe someone's state of mind, an noun. 
The usage here is a little strange to me (they seem to shout it like a battlecry which is obviously not what the phrase is intended as). It is akin to any of us yelling "inner peace" before charging into battle. I can only understand it as a state these people want to achieve after death, dying pure and not be polluted by the kabane virus and turned.